# Request body in post method java

Tags: java, post, httpclient

I am using Apache Commons HttpClient Post method. In post method there are two ways to set request body.

1) `setRequestBody(NameValuePair [])`

2) `setRequestEntity(RequestEntity)`

In my case, the input for the above methods would be json Object. How can i send json Object as requestBody ?

Comment: please provide more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the second option:

```
httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

String json = "{ \"key\" : \"value\" }";
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json);
httpPost.setEntity(entity);
```

Comment: But i wasn't able to get proper response message. I pass ticket as one paramater. When i post this using postman it works fine but here i get error message saying invalid ticket. i don't know where i go wrong.

Comment: @kushi you have to add a lot more info if you want any specific help. Post your code, specifically what you send and receive, and where the error is.

Comment: I use setParameter method to set some parameters before setEntity method. When i attach there parameters in the URL without using setParameter method i get response. But when i use this method I get error saying something wrong with the parameter i have given.

example: someurl/parama="avalue"&paramb="bvalue"&paramc="cvalue" If i give paramters along url its working but when i set using setParamter("parama","avalue") i get an error saying parama is incorrect. Am i clear?

Comment: Then just use the way that works - why make things more complicated than neecessary?